# How to download all files from http address

Tags: c#, winforms, download

I've tried many things about this issue. I've downloaded only one image. Here is the code

```
imageUrl = new Uri("http://"SomeIpAdress"/oykun/Yöksis.png");
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Downloaded");
client.DownloadFileAsync(imageUrl, "C:\\Downloaded\\Yöksis.png");
```

By this way, I got specific png that I gave the name of it. But I want to download all of the images inside the http address. How to do this?

Comment: You are trying to download a single image not all images in the path.

Comment: I'am asking that when I want all images from that folder. like *.png

Comment: @OykunYenal - I don't understand. Is that an answer or another question? In any case the, answer to your 1st question is no. You cannot download all files from a web address if you don't know them by name. Knowing all files by name on a web address requires the web server to grand you (a web user, so that means everyone who has the web address) file-list privileges. That's an amazing security hole though, that's why I asked whether your question was serious.

Comment: I got my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most websites don't provide a way for you to list the files on the server. Some images don't even exist on the server, but are generated on the spot when you request them.

If the web master wants you to be able to download all files, he might have an FTP server you can use - which is a more common way to access "all (public) files on a server".

By the way IIS (and perhaps other servers) does allow you to show a directory listing, so if this is *your* website, you can enable this and parse the directory listing page. I would still go with FTP though.

Comment: It is a server that I have a connection. So I can reach the files but I could not do it with code.

Comment: @OykunYenal you can compare this with a telephone without a phone book or number lookup service - you can start dialing 000000000, then 000000001 - but there is no (default) way to know which numbers are actually connected without trying them individually.